# UIAlertView not disabling all interaction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uialertview

Is it possible to use interaction with other windows when a UIAlertView is showing.

Solutions i thought about is an extra UIWindow falling over the UIAlertView window or an alert with a smaller size.

Has anybody any suggestions/solutions how to achieve this?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I have to use a UIAlertView instance. I already found a way to recognize the moment when an UIAlertView is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought create custom view with your alert text and button and show it as UIAlertView. Clicking on button hide that view. Which will solve your purpose. Below Code you can use for the same. Plz adjust x/y/height/width as per your requirement.

```
UIView *customAlert = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)];
UILabel *lblText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,30)];
lblText.text =@"Your alert text";

[customAlert addSubView:lblText];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(hideAlertView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(30.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0);
[customAlert addSubview:button];

[self.view addSubView:customAlert];

-(IBAction)hideAlertView:(id)sender
{
     [customAlert removeFromSuperView];
}
```

**EDIT**

As UIAlertView is of MODAL behavior you can not touch any other part of your application until it is dismissed.

Comment: Ok. That would be my normal solution, but i have to use a UIAlertView instance. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I see your solution. And like i said, i would normally use it. But you don't use a UIAlertView and i <u>have</u> to (badly enough)... So my question would be, can a lay a view/window over the modal UIAlertView?

Answer (score 0):

Swift Solution:

```
  // Define a view
  var popup:UIView!
  func showAlert() {
    // customise your view
    popup = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200))
    popup.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    // show on screen
    self.view.addSubview(popup)

  }

  func dismissView(){
    // Dismiss the view from here
    popup.removeFromSuperview()
  }
```